# 'Counter' object has no attribute 'count'

Tags: python, list, collections, counter

There are two lists and I want to check how many of elements are duplicate. Assuming list one is `l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` and list two is `l2 = ['a', 'f', 'c', 'g']`. Since `a` and `c` are in both lists, therefore, the output should be `2` which means there are two elements that repeated in both lists.  Below is my code and I want to count how many `2` are in counter. I am not sure how to count that.

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
l2 = ['a', 'f', 'c', 'g']
from collections import Counter
    c1 = Counter(l1)
    c2 = Counter(l2)
    sum = c1+c2
    z=sum.count(2)
```

Comment: The error says it all. `sum.count()` isn't a thing. You will need to find a different way to solve the problem.

Comment: Question...does each element only appear once in each list?

Comment: The [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) don't have any `count` method for a Counter object, you get the count in a totally different way. Why do you think `count()` would work? Which item do you expect it to return the count of?

Comment: @ Code-Apprentice yes, only appear once in each list.

Comment: @Bob Then use a `set` as shown in the answer below, not `Counter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is `set.intersection` (if there are no duplicates in each list):

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
l2 = ['a', 'f', 'c', 'g']

print(len(set(l1).intersection(l2)))
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: This will only work if each element only appears once in each list.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice This seems to be the case for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Every time we use a counter it converts the lists into dict. So it is throwing the error. You can simply change the number of lists and run the following code to get the exact number of duplicate values.

```
# Duplicate elements in 2 lists
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
l2 = ['a', 'f', 'c', 'g']# a,c are duplicate
from collections import Counter

c1 = Counter(l1)
c2 = Counter(l2)
sum = c1+c2
j = sum.values()
print(sum)
print(j)

v = 0
for i in j:
    if i>1:
        v = v+1

print("Duplicate in lists:", v)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'f': 1, 'g': 1})
dict_values([2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
Duplicate in lists: 2
```